# UnboundedLocalError in function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Why below code does not work ? Where is a mistake ?

[image]

Comment: Never ever use the same name for variables and functions. That will override the function with the variable and error on you in the future. This particular error, however, appears to be because the `confusion_matrix` function is undefined. Have you imported or defined the function somewhere prior to using it here?

Comment: No screenshots of code please. [Edit] your question with the code and traceback as text.

Comment: It assumes that confusion_matrix as a variable and not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would be a NameError; but because you use the same variable name as a function, python creates a variable on line 3, called `confusion_matrix`. It then proceeds with the assignment, but because a name is encountered that has been declared but not assigned, it throws an error.

Even if you imported the name `confusion_matrix` correctly, it is overridden by the assignment in progress.

Comment: Exactly right. You **cannot** give a variable the same name as a method. Basically the error means Python is confused as to what to use. You must change the name of your ```confusion_matrix``` variable

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable in the function, it becomes a local variable, and the local variables always get priority over the global variables with the same name. Your code is similar to this which gives the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment"

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a+b
def sumPrint():
    sum = sum(3,4)
    print(sum)

sumPrint()
```

I would suggest you not use the same variable name in a local variable and the function. It should be like this

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a+b
def sumPrint():
    sumResult = sum(3,4)
    print(sumResult)

sumPrint()
```

Your problem `confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(a,b).`